# Hiding transition in Gtk

Tags: gtk, vala, genie

This is a continuation of a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36807850/revealing-and-hiding-search-entry-gtk?s=9|4.9650) on the Gtk.SearchEntry widget.

In that question I manage to reveal the entry widget upon clicking in the icon, now I want the widget to disappear after it loses focus.

The approach used now was with:

```
    search_entry.icon_release.connect (hide_search)
```

And defined hide_search as:

```
def hide_search()
    search_button_revealer.set_reveal = true
    search_entry_revealer.set_reveal = false
    show_all()
```

However, this does not solve the problem. The entire code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/0HqA65AY).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be grabbing the wrong signal. The one you have is for when you click the button inside the entry while the one you need is `focus_out_event`, this is the vala code that makes what you want :)

```
search_entry.focus_out_event.connect (() => {
    // Make sure the entry is empty so you don't 
    // close it out on the user
    if (search_entry.get_text () == "") {
        hide_search ();
    }

    return false;
});
```

Comment: I keep getting: `Cannot convert from `Application.hide_search' to `Gtk.Widget.focus_out_event' search_entry.focus_out_event.connect (hide_search)` with that solution. I updated the code in the pastebin link from the question.

Comment: The callback requires a `Gdk.EventFocus` argument and must return a `bool`.  See https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Widget.focus_out_event.html For Genie, I /think/ the syntax is `def hide_search(e: Gdk.Event) : bool`